# How to concatenate two cells without space in excel?

Tags: excel

I have two columns in my excel sheet like that:

```
1234  |  548
21596 |  1875
```

When i concatenate this two field by doing   `=A1&B1`  then it give me   `1234 548` with space between the two values.

Why it put a space and how can I erase it? It's for populate a database, so I don't want a space between my values. Any ideas please?

Comment: When I try this it doesn't add a space (Excel 2010).  Are you sure there aren't any spaces in your original data, e.g. "1234 "?

Comment: Yes, effectively I have some space after my first value. I've look on internet and I find the fonction SUPPRESPACE to erase those space but I can't make it work. I never work with excel

Comment: See http://www.rondebruin.nl/clean.htm. If this is text copied from the net then you probably have the CHAR(160) problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just have an extra space before your second values or behind your first values, causing you to get a space. But you can use the `TRIM()` function to delete spaces.

```
=TRIM(A1)&TRIM(B1)
```

Seen as though you're French, here's the [link](http://office.microsoft.com/fr-fr/excel-help/supprespace-HP005209321.aspx) to the `SUPPRESPACE()` function.

```
=SUPPRESPACE(A1)&SUPPRESPACE(B1)
```

Comment: also applies to VBA (from [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) - When numbers are converted to strings, a leading space is always reserved for the sign of number. If number is positive, the returned string contains a leading space and the plus sign is implied.)

Comment: and `CStr` does not appear to suffer from this ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions#cstr-function-example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions#cstr-function-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the Find/Replace feature to find (space) and replace with (nothing) and press Replace all...

Answer (score 0):

Copy the spaces(s) you want to delete in one cell of your column. 
highlight all cells you want to remove the space(s) from. 
select the Replace function and paste the copied space(s) in top box. 
leave 'replace with' box empty. 
click on replace all. 
they will be removed

Answer (score -1):

This has always worked for me:

A1&""&B2 = two cells w/o spaces