# Excel table to text

Tags: excel

I have an excel table formatted(with header row included just for reference) like so:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |  | 5 | 2 | 2 |  | - | 2 |

I would like it formatted as text like so:

522 522 -2

Whenever I paste into word and convert to text it prints a space in between cells that are adjacent like this (underline as space):

5_2_2_ *5_2_2* _ -_2

I also tried pasting into other text editors and VScode without success.

I have several lines of this data and it's actually longer than the example so it's fairly cumbersome to manually delete the spaces. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in excel/word.

Comment: This is not really specific to programming (off-topic)... the typical approach would be to use regex, but writing a program /excel formula to transform the data is also common.

Comment: Yes. There is way. You question is not clear. Do you want to delete blank cells then shift data cells to left?

Comment: @Harun24HR sorry I don't know why my question was cached and didn't keep all the text. I edited it with the format I'm looking for. I believe this is more of a Macro/VBA question hence the stack overflow post.

Comment: Looks like excel-formulas will do the job. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084366/how-to-concatenate-two-cells-without-space-in-excel